# Stochastic integral where the integrator is zero in probability

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-integrals

We are given a continuous semimartingale $Y$ and a continuous process $B$ of finite variation. Hence, we know that $\langle B \rangle$, the quadratic covariation of $B$, is zero in probability.

I now think that
$$
\int_0^t Y_s \text{ d}\langle B \rangle_s = 0 \text{ (a.s.)}
$$
but I have no clue how I can prove this, or even know that it is indeed true.

Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 1):

As you pointed out, we know that $\langle B \rangle_t = 0$ in probability for $t \geq 0$. In fact, $\langle B \rangle_t = 0$ almost surely (mind that the exceptional set may depend on $t$). *Indeed:* By definition,

$$\langle B \rangle_t = \mathbb{P}-\lim_{|\Pi| \to 0} V_t(B,\Pi)$$

where

$$V_t(B,\Pi) := \sum_{t_k \in \Pi} (B_{t_k}-B_{t_{k-1}})^2.$$

Here $\Pi = \{0=t_0 < \ldots < t_n=t\}$ denotes a partition of the interval $[0,t]$ with mesh size $|\Pi|$.  Since

$$|V_t(B,\Pi)| \leq \left( \sup_{|r-s| \leq |\Pi|; r,s \in [0,t]} |B_r-B_s| \right) \sum_{t_k \in \Pi} |B_{t_k}-B_{t_{k-1}}|$$

it follows from the fact that $(B_t)_{t \geq 0}$ has continuous sample paths of bounded variation that $V_t(B,\Pi) \to 0$ almost surely as the mesh size $|\Pi|$ tends to zero. Hence, $\langle B \rangle_t=0$ almost surely.

---

Now, since $(B_t)_{t \geq 0}$ is continuous, we also know that $(\langle B \rangle_t)_{t \geq 0}$ has continuous sample paths. Hence, by continuity, we get

$$\mathbb{P}(\forall s \in [0,t]: \langle B \rangle_s = 0) = 1$$

for all $t \geq 0$. Now it follows from the very definition of the Riemann-Stieltjes integral that

$$\int_0^t Y_s \, d \langle B \rangle_s = 0$$

almost surely.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but for all I know, we only know that $\langle B \rangle_t = 0$ _in probability_, as this was proved in our lecture notes. 

Does the result even hold almost surely? If so, do you have a proof (or reference)?

Comment: @Ghostface Which definition (of quadratic variation) do you use/know?

Comment: If $\Pi=\{t_0,\dots,t_N\}$ is a partition of $[0,t]$, we have for a process $X$ $$V_t(X,\Pi) = \sum_{k=1}^{n}(X_{t_k}-X_{t_{k-1}})^2.$$. We then let $\langle X \rangle_t$ be the limit of $V_t(X,\Pi)$, where the mesh of the partition $\Pi$ tends to zero.

Comment: @Ghostface Okay. So, $$V_t(B,\Pi) \leq \bigg( \sup_{|r-s| \leq \text{mesh} \, \Pi; r,s \in [0,t]} |B_r-B_s| \bigg) \cdot \sum_{k=1}^n |B_{t_k}-B_{t_{k-1}}|.$$ Now use that $(B_t)_{t \geq 0}$ has continuous sample paths of bounded variation to conclude $V_t(B,\Pi) \to 0$ almost surely as the mesh size tends to $0$.

Comment: Thanks, saz, that really helped!

Comment: @Ghostface You are welcome. If you find the answer helpful, you can upvote/accept it by clicking on the up arrow/tick next to it.